# The position of 给

Tags: grammar, word

I‘ve notice that sometimes 给 changes its position in the sentece. Look at these examples:
• 我发给你一个邮件
• 我给你发一个邮件

Both are correct but what different meaning/shadow do they express?

Comment: 我发一个邮件给你 is also correct

Comment: Really??? Are you sure? I've always thought that 给 had a specific position in the sentence, meaning before the main verb! Is it like that or not?? Why sometimes we can change its position?

Comment: It depends on the point of view you want to emphasize. Let's say `我发给你一个邮件` is the normal order; `我给你发一个邮件` emphasize the object of `to you`; `我发一个邮件给你` emphasize the action of `send a mail`.

Comment: it sound like 
"I send you an email" vs "I send an email to you", they mean the same right ?

Answer (score 3):

**Sentence 1:** `我发给你一个邮件`

`发给` is its own meaning of "issued/transmitted/sent", whereas 给 just means give. So the first sentence:

`我发给你一个邮件` = I transmitted/sent an e-mail to you.

**Sentence 2:** `我给你发一个邮件`

`给` is more of a connection/preposition, like `to`.
So, It's more like `I to you send an e-mail`.

Like you said, both are equally correct and used with equal frequency.

Comment: Am I wrong that "我给你发一个邮件“ could also be interpreted as "I send an email for you", as in "you were to lazy to do it so I did it instead."?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take it this way, correct me if I am wrong

- 我 is the subject, 发 is the verb, 一个邮件 is the object.
- 给你 is like to you, need to be together
- It is like I sent a letter to you == I sent you a letter.